# CREATE DATABASE using phpmyadmin in online server

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I install phpMyAdmin on my subdomain for my clients to access their Databases, Because I can't give my Cpanel Login to them.
But my problem is when they need to create a new database, they can't do it from phpMyAdmin and they face this error

> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY
> 'root';

[image]

And I try to create a DB using phpMyAdmin, login from cPanel but I had the same error.

No worry I can create and manage user and DB from cPanel, But the problem is I have to create a database myself when my client needs DBS.

So has I have an option for this, any type?

Comment: this is no error message please add the complete error message

Comment: The image shows that a user is trying to create a database but doesn't have proper permissions. Simply grant the users privileges to create databases and they'll be able to. The text you've pasted isn't actually an error message, it's an unrelated SQL command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, this error means the MySQL user does not have the required privilege to create a database. These are some options you could do:

- Grant their user all privileges on all databases (**not recommended**):

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'sserver_sserver'@'localhost';

- Create the database yourself and give their user all privileges on that specific database:

CREATE DATABASE my;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my.* TO 'sserver_sserver'@'localhost';

- Give their user all privileges to databases beginning with a certain prefix such as their business name which will allow them to create and work on as many databases as they need:

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON 'businessname_%'.* TO 'sserver_sserver'@'localhost';